# How to open a url on browser using expect script?

Tags: bash, expect

My bash script when runs produce a URL (basically a login URL to azure), wherein the user has to login to Azure account. I want to automate this using expect script so that the URL automatically opens up in the browser.

This is the kind of URL that my shell script produces :

```
Please log into Microsoft Azure
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ******* to authenticate.
```

Comment: What OS are you using? On a Mac, you'd do `open "$url"`, on Linux `xdg-open "$url"`

Comment: Thanks glen, I am using mac. When i do open "$url", I get error : couldn't open "https://microsoft.com/devicelogin": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open https://microsoft.com/devicelogin"

Comment: Requires the leading  `hrrp://` so that open knows it's a URL

Comment: if you're logging int azure, proably powershell.  it's quite cross-platform these days, and even on github...plus it's powerful.  probably will do far more than what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on JS usage on the webpage, you will not be able to login using expect / curl.
You might want to consider using selenium with firefox, which can record a standard login session and replay it later.
You might then fun firefox headless with selenium to login.